# Django REST routers

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-urls

I'm new to Django REST, and I'm trying to understand the concepts behind it.
I have setup the following API

serializers.py

```
class StudentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):   
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ('classroom', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'gender', 'birthday')

class ClassroomSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    students = StudentSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Classroom
        depth = 1
        fields = ('school', 'academic_year', 'classroom', 'floor', 'students')
```

views.py

```
def index(request):
    return render_to_response('school_app/base.html', RequestContext(request))

class StudentViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Student.objects.all()
    serializer_class = StudentSerializer

class ClassroomViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Classroom.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ClassroomSerializer
```

urls.py

```
router = routers.SimpleRouter()

router.register(r'classrooms', ClassroomViewSet)
router.register(r'students', StudentViewSet)

urlpatterns = router.urls

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
    url(r'^classrooms/$', school_app.views.ClassroomViewSet.as_view({'get': 'list'}), name='classroom-list'),
    url(r'^students/$', school_app.views.StudentViewSet.as_view({'get': 'list'}), name='student-list'),
    url(r'^students/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)/$', school_app.views.StudentViewSet.as_view({'get': 'list'}), name='student-list'),
    url(r'^', 'school_app.views.index', name='index-page'),
    #url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
]
```

And I can't understand one thing. If I write urls.py like this

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
]
```

I can see the two lists (students and classrooms) when going to "/classrooms/" or "/students/", and when clicking, like, "/students/1", I get that particular student instance - but the "index" view doesn't work.

When urls.py is written like this

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
    url(r'^classrooms/$', school_app.views.ClassroomViewSet.as_view({'get': 'list'}), name='classroom-list'),
    url(r'^students/$', school_app.views.StudentViewSet.as_view({'get': 'list'}), name='student-list'),
    url(r'^students/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)/$', school_app.views.StudentViewSet.as_view({'get': 'list'}), name='student-list'),
    url(r'^', 'school_app.views.index', name='index-page'),
]
```

I get the list when going to "/classrooms/" or "/students"; I'm getting the "index" view too, and I'm not getting a particular instance of the two lists, but instead I get the "index" view.

Why's that?

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it very manually. Use the DRF [DefaultRouter](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#defaultrouter) and have it take care of the instance/list nitty gritty stuff.

```
from rest_framework import routers

router = routers.DefaultRouter()

router.register('classrooms', school_app.views.ClassroomViewSet)
router.register('students', school_app.views.StudentViewSet)

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
    # ... other urls...
)
```

Comment: Is that ok if I'm consuming it with an Angular JS app?

Comment: Yes, it's ok.   This part doesn't have anything to do with it being used in AngularJS.  It is just about creating the right  URL->View mappings.  I use my DRF service to serve my AngularJS front-end client.